# Rspec testing POROs included in models rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec

In my Order model I include a PORO class "ShipmentHandler". This PORO is located like this: app/models/order/shipment_handler.rb

I invoke this in my Order model like so:

```
def assign_shipments
  ShipmentHandler.new(self).assign_shipments
end
```

My PORO looks like:

```
class Order
    class ShipmentHandler 
        def initialize(order)
            @set_some_variables
        end

        def some_methods
        end
    end
end
```

I'm trying to create spec to test the methods in my ShipmentHandler class. I'm not sure how to do this as I keep getting errors like `uninitialized constant ShipmentHandler`

I've tried to add it to my order_spec.rb like so:

```
describe Order do 
    describe Order::ShipmentHandler do
    end
end
```

and:

```
describe Order do 
    describe ShipmentHandler do
    end
end
```

Neither work. I've also tried creating a spec in spec/models/order/shipment_handler_spec.rb
This also failed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following way of writing specs worked for me when I made some assumptions on what your `Order` class looks like with the nested `ShipmentHandler` class:

```
class Order
  def assign_shipments
    ShipmentHandler.new(self).assign_shipments
  end

  class ShipmentHandler
    def initialize(order)
      @order = order
    end

    def some_methods
    end
  end
end

RSpec.describe Order do
  it { is_expected.to be_a Order }
end

# Method 1
RSpec.describe Order::ShipmentHandler do
  subject(:shipment_handler) { described_class.new(Order.new) }

  it { is_expected.to be_a Order::ShipmentHandler }
end

# Method 2
class Order
  RSpec.describe ShipmentHandler do
    subject(:shipment_handler) { described_class.new(Order.new) }

    it { is_expected.to be_a Order::ShipmentHandler }
  end
end
```

Comment: You sir, are my hero. Thanks a lot!